# Unable to add target to UIButton inside UITableViewCell using cell prototypes and storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have cell prototypes set up inside my storyboard, with a UIButton which I want to select to perform a specific action.  Here is my code;

`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ProjectCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell){
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        titleLabel.text = @"New York";

        UIImageView *mainImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        [mainImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nyc_temp.png"]];

        UITextView *descText = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        [descText setText:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..."];


        UIButton *selectButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:104];

        [selectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)selectButtonPressed//:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"");
}
```

`

The selectButtonPressed is never called.  I know that the selectButton is the correct button as I can change the text, the background colour etc just below the viewWithTag line, why will the target not stick?

UPDATE:  I have changed my code to use a custom cell class, but still no luck, and as one person suggested explicity cast the button to a UIButton (which shouldn't be required I would have thought?)

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TemplateTableViewCell";

    TemplateTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell){
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        titleLabel.text = @"New York";

        [cell.mainImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nyc_temp.png"]];

        [cell.desc setText:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..."];

        [cell.selectButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [(UIButton *)cell.selectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)selectButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"");
}
```

Still doesn't work, I can interact with the button in every other way except for being able to set the target method.  Is it something to do with touch hierarchy?

Comment: why you have commented id(sender) try to uncomment that without any event and assign colon in selector.

Comment: essentially, I have tried every combination of (id)sender (id)sender withEvent and without, nothing changes the behaviour

Comment: why you dont create deligate in TemplateTableViewCell and assign it to ViewController implementing UITableView ?

Comment: @collibhoy Have you tried breakpointing inside the `if` block to verify a) that `cell.selectButton` is not `nil`; b) the target is actually being added to the button (e.g. by sending `allTargets` to it and inspecting the set of targets added)?

Comment: Thanks Maurice, that helped.  The button was set, but the cells userInteraction was being disabled in another part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the CELL userInteration was being disabled in another part of the code erroneously, and this was preventing any touch input whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Set action for table view cell button using this code

```
[(UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:104] addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and define the method like this with sender

```
-(void)selectButtonPressed:(id)sender        
{        
  NSLog(@"Method called");        
}
```

Comment: you are not using cell.contenView

Answer (score 0):

If you have created selectButton in prototype cell then all subviews are added in container view of table view cell, so to get your desired button with tag you have to call like:

```
[(UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:104] addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And make sure you have given `104` as `tag` value for your `selectButton` and also check you have not give `104 tag` value to any other view.

Comment: Then start debugging your code starting with statement if(cell){... with breakpoint to check either control goes inside the condition? And if controls goes in the are you getting button object or getting nil.

Comment: I am getting the button - read the question, I am able to set the text of the button, set the colour of the button, just not the target.